# Broadcom Wi-Fi Adapter not recognized

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm trying to get wireless card working, 
Conditions:

```
ubuntu 12.04 3
sony vaio duo 13
Wi-Fi Adapter Broadcom BCM43241 (802.11a/b/g/n)
```

However, first of all

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 0a0c (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
(shows no result)
```

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6136429/)'s the result for dmesg 
And it seems nothing indicating the network card, even though it works in dual-booted Win8 fine (no hardware problem).

How could I make Broadcom Wi-Fi Adapter show up in lspci? Or, is there a way around to make online?

Thanks in advance.

(edit1)
Responding to the first answer below, here's my update.
I have ubuntu 12.04-3 with Linux Kernel 3.8.0, so the kernel brcmfmac exists. However, this command

```
$ sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

doesn't change the situation.

In my understanding, the device must be recognized before the driver is installed as the official(?) tutorial says. (google "ubuntu WirelessTroubleShootingGuide" as I am not allowed to put more hyperlink.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers for [your card didn't make it into the Linux kernel until 3.7](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.7_DriverArch) (also see [this](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1388591/)), and I believe 12.04 is still using 3.2.x.  You will need to upgrade to 13.04 or else [compile and install the driver yourself](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211).  If you're not familiar with compiling and installing drivers in Linux, then I would upgrade to 13.04.

Comment: I see, I was aware of the link for compiling the module. But I was not sure I can do it with hardware not detected at all as described in the question. And I didn't even know it would be available in 13.04.　Thank, Freedom_Ben!

Comment: I have some update -- I'm glad if you check it out..

Comment: @yuyu that is really strange.  I would now be inclined to think hardware problem but you say it works fine in Windows...  I'll have to think on this

Comment: I have the same problem here in Arch Linux. This BCM43241 wifi card just seems to be completely non-existent when in Arch, but it works just fine in Windows.