# “No Network Devices Available” for BCM43241(SDIO) after fresh install of 13.10

Tags: broadcom

I have a laptop vaio duo 13 which has a broadcom 43241 wireless card. My problem is similar to this one [Broadcom Wi-Fi Adapter not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348497/broadcom-wi-fi-adapter-not-recognized) .

I tried to install the driver brcmfmac(SDIO) here http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211 and copied the nvram to /lib/firmware/brcm as the page tells, but this didn't work.

Most questions I searched are about br43 such as [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx) . I tried part of solution like unblock all in rfkill, put an # in front of blacklist bcm43xx, but none worked. I didn't uninstall or install any drivers such as b43-installer, b43legacy-installer, bcmwl-kernel-source (only tried b43-fwcutter) because they are not compatible with bcm43241.

Above is all information I can provide for help. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add any further information you can find about the device from: sudo lshw or: dmesg | grep -i 14e4

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I think it's just because the wireless card is too new for the current kernel. @chili555

Comment: It would be very nice for you to share the solution so others can get theirs working as well. Can we post the bin and txt files somewhere?

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I upload this to dropbox and post the link here @chili555

Comment: Very fine. What exactly did you then do with these items?

Comment: copy them to /lib/firmware/brcm and execute sudo modprobe brcmfmac-sdio

Comment: **Do not put your answer in your question**. Use the filed below to add your answer, also don't add SOLVED tag in your question. Accept the answer that solved your problem. **this is not a forum.THIS IS SPARTA!**

Comment: I think it is sudo modprobe brcmfmac. There is no module brcmfmac-sdio in Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 4):

*Found in the question, written by the OP.*

> After contacted a developer of broadcom, he gave me mails between him
>   and an user who had same issue but have successfully solved this. The
>   user helped me by sending another nvram and firmware (a bin and a txt)
>   and it worked. I think it's just because the wireless card is too new
>   for the current kernel (correct me if I say something wrong as a
>   novice of linux).
>
> I attach them here
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m9n4qolf76iz11/brcmfmac-sdio.zip
>
> copy them to /lib/firmware/brcm and execute sudo modprobe
>   brcmfmac-sdio, the problem solved.