# Reducing colour depth to 16 bit without losing panels and launcher

Tags: command-line, xorg, launcher, colors

Earlier today, I had help solving a problem [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496816/solved-menu-bars-and-launcher-missing-after-tampering-with-xorg-conf) where creating an xorg.conf file, with colour depth reduced to 16 bit in my 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 had caused my panels and launcher to go MIA, and messing up my .desktop files. This was solved, but how can I prevent this from happening again?

I'm attempting to play a game called Docking Station, which requires the display setting to be set to 16 bit (high color).

Is there a way to set xorg.conf to allow 16 bit without losing the panels (I have no idea what causes 16 bit to wipe them away anyway)

Is there a way to create shortcuts to run the commands needed to create and fill the xorg.conf file, and to reset it after I'm done playing, and if needed, to run the commands needed to restore the mess ups (like `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`, `unity --reset-icons & disown` and `sudo chmod +x /home/jarle/Desktop/applications/*.desktop`)?

Answer (score 2):

make a backup copy of your current `xorg.conf` file like:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

make a copy of your xorg.conf like:

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.game
```

edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.game` file to contain the settings you need/want for your game.

```
gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.game
```

write a bash script that copies your game conf file over your standard conf file

add a line to launch your game

add the lines you require to restore things back to normal.

Save the script and modify permissions so that you can execute it.

use the script you've written to test launching your game.

**Note:** I've never had any issues running a lower colour depth game at a higher colour depth so I doubt any of this is necessary.